# Need recommendation for good resource on troubleshooting android using logcat and the console

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-logcat

everyone. Can anyone recommend a good resource that gives insight on how to troubleshoot android using the LogCat and the Console? Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: What do you want? You need to be more clearer. You need a way to interpret logcat messages.?

Comment: I usually copy/paste the invariant part of a message to google in double quotes. This search often helps interpreting errors.

Answer (score 1):

I never saw anything written, but here are a few tips (or, at least, this is how I do it):

- Tracing the error in the stack:

  - When you're troubleshooting after a force close, then always look for the `ERROR` part of the logcat. It will be followed by **the exception type**.
  - If you get a not-that-useful `java.lang.RuntimeException`, search below for **the original exception thrown**, e.g. `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`
  - These exceptions will be followed by the **stack trace** of your app. You can find in there **where the exception was thrown** (class, method and line) and which methods called it. Try to find your package in there and figure out how it got to that exception.
  - If it is an exception you don't know about, **google it**: I usually use "java 6 xxx.xxx.xxException" or "android xxx.xxx.xxException" to quickly get the link to the API documentation about that exception.
  - Then **read the docs about the class that is throwing the exception** (e.g., which are the cases it can be null, etc.)
- Customizing the logs

  - I abuse of the `Log.d("MyClass", "Some variable =" + variable);` . It ends up to be very informative. Some times I just **use the log to check** where in an `if`/`else` tree am I or to trace constructors (useful to know if I am reusing an object, or creating a new one some times).
  - If the logcat is too noisy, I use grep and **a particular marker for my logs**, e.g., `Log.d("***> MyClass", "Some variable =" + variable);` or `Log.d("***> MyClass2", "onCreate()");`, I filter those using a simple `adb logcat | grep '\*\*\*>'`
  - You can quickly **filter** for errors in the log using `adb logcat *:E`
- When everything else fails: **Post the trace here :)**